# Does Armory work with a pruned copy of the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, client, armory, storage-footprint, pruning

I'm recovering a wallet from Armory and the blockchain is taking too much space. My HD is 500 GB big but none of my partitions have more then 70 GB left. The folder `.bitcoin/blocks` already uses 37 GB and Armory is only at 52%. Any solution to this?

Comment: Hey Zaico, I've edited your question with a more speaking title pertaining to what I understand your question to aim at. I hope you agree, otherwise please feel free to further edit and improve it.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, you'll need to make space for a full copy of the blockchain somewhere. AFAIK, Armory rescans the blockchain in order to build its own database only *after* Bitcoin Core has fully synchronized. Therefore, Armory needs access to a full copy of the blockchain which is currently about 118GiB. Armory's database itself then will take more than 20GiB additionally.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a BitcoinD server then you can enable pruning which is enabled since v0.12 (with Wallet support - see https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.12.0).
You can then specify the amount of space you want to allocate for the blockchain data. For instance 550Mb or 5Gb - entirely up to you.

Comment: I would expect pruning to be incompatible with Armory (but I don't know for sure).

Comment: As of Armory 0.96.5 this is still the case, that one needs full (not pruned) bitcoind blocks history for Armory to work properly.